# SSL Connection issue with Mongodb using Perl

Tags: mongodb, perl, ssl

I am trying to connect Mongodb server (using SSL) in Perl script but failed to connect.

#### Source code:

```
use strict;

use IO::Socket::SSL;
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::OID;

my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(
    host => 'mongodb://username:password@ip_address1:port_number, ip_address2:port_number,ip_address3:port_number/myDB?ssl=true&replicaSet=mongo123',
    ssl  => {
        SSL_ca_file   => " certificates/chain_prod.pem",
        SSL_cert_file => " certificates/cert.pem",
    },
    auth_mechanism => "MONGODB-X509",
    username       => " CN=XXXXXXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXXX,O=XXXXXXX,ST=XXXXXXXXXX,C=XX ",
    # using openssl x509 -in certs/client.pem -inform PEM -subject -nameopt RFC2253
);

my $db       = $client->get_database( "mydb" );
my $coll     = $db->get_collection( "customers" );
my $messages = $coll->find;

while ( my $msg = $messages->next ) {
    print $msg;
}
```

#### Error

> NPP_EXEC: "Run Perl"
>   NPP_SAVE: C:\Users\royabhix\Desktop\perl_program\MysqlDataBaseConnection.pl
>   CD: C:\Users\royabhix\Desktop\perl_program
>   Current directory: C:\Users\royabhix\Desktop\perl_program
>   C:\perl64\bin\perl "MysqlDataBaseConnection.pl"
>   Process started (PID=11400) >>>
>   MongoDB::UsageError: invalid field password in MONGODB-X509 credential at (eval 595) line 291.
>   MongoDB::_Credential::new(undef, "mechanism", "MONGODB-X509", "mechanism_properties", HASH(0x5935f10), "username", "user123", "password", ...) called at C:/Perl64/site/lib/MongoDB/MongoClient.pm line 1181
>   MongoDB::MongoClient::_build__credential(MongoDB::MongoClient=HASH(0x594db50)) called at (eval 450) line 21
>   MongoDB::MongoClient::_credential(MongoDB::MongoClient=HASH(0x594db50)) called at C:/Perl64/site/lib/MongoDB/MongoClient.pm line 1149
>   MongoDB::MongoClient::_build__topology(MongoDB::MongoClient=HASH(0x594db50)) called at (eval 446) line 21
>   MongoDB::MongoClient::_topology(MongoDB::MongoClient=HASH(0x594db50)) called at C:/Perl64/site/lib/MongoDB/MongoClient.pm line 1291
>   MongoDB::MongoClient::BUILD(MongoDB::MongoClient=HASH(0x594db50), HASH(0x62e87f8)) called at (eval 590) line 1014
>   MongoDB::MongoClient::new(undef, "host", "mongodb://username1:password123\@ip_address:port_number,1"..., "ssl", HASH(0xa5dc68), "auth_mechanism", "MONGODB-X509", "username", ...) called at MysqlDataBaseConnection.pl line 4
>   <<< Process finished (PID=11400). (Exit code 255)
>
> ================ READY ================

#### Without SSL (Mongodb + perl):

```
use MongoDB ();
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(host => 'localhost', port => 27017);

my $db   = $client->get_database( 'mydb');

my $messages_coll = $db->get_collection('customers');

my $messages = $messages_coll->find;
while (my $p = $messages->next) {
    print Dumper $p;
}
```

#### Output:

```
NPP_EXEC: "Run Perl"
NPP_SAVE: C:\Users\royabhix\Desktop\perl_program\MongoDBConnection.pl
CD: C:\Users\royabhix\Desktop\perl_program
Current directory: C:\Users\royabhix\Desktop\perl_program
C:\perl64\bin\perl "MongoDBConnection.pl"
Process started (PID=16796) >>>
$VAR1 = {
          'password' => 'intel123',
          'username' => 'rpn',
          '_id' => bless( {
                          'value' => '5b3b96ea7517d164f102d614'
                        }, 'MongoDB::OID' )
        };
$VAR1 = {
          '_id' => bless( {
                          'value' => '5b3b96f27517d164f102d615'
                        }, 'MongoDB::OID' ),
          'username' => 'faizkhax',
          'password' => 'intel456'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          '_id' => bless( {
                          'value' => '5b3b96f27517d164f102d616'
                        }, 'MongoDB::OID' ),
          'username' => 'kunal',
          'password' => 'intel789'
        };
<<< Process finished (PID=16796). (Exit code 0)
================ READY ================
```

#### The above code snippet is working fine as SSL is not being applied here.

#### But I want to have the same code with SSL.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Edit the question to format your code slightly better.

Comment: ###Without SSL (Mongodb+perl):
use MongoDB ();
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(host => 'localhost', port => 27017);
my $db   = $client->get_database( 'mydb');
my $messages_coll = $db->get_collection('customers');
my $messages = $messages_coll->find;
while (my $p = $messages->next) {
    print Dumper $p;
}

###O/P
$VAR1 = {
          'password' => 'intel123',
          'username' => 'royabhix',
          '_id' => bless( {
                          'value' => '5b3b96ea7517d164f102d614'
                        }, 'MongoDB::OID' )
        };

Comment: Did you try removing the username and password from the URL in `host` attribute? (Also no need to obfuscate them in your question, they appear in clear text in your error message dump... so you now need to change at least this password `y2sK...`)

Comment: In cases like that you would ideally also need to give the version number of your MongoDB module, as well as perl while you are at it. Things can change depending on the version...

Answer (score 1):

Your error message comes from this line:
https://metacpan.org/source/MONGODB/MongoDB-v2.0.0/lib/MongoDB/_Credential.pm#L211

If you study the code above it, you see it depends on:

```
'MONGODB-X509' => {
    password             => sub { ! length },
    source               => sub { $_ eq '$external' },
    mechanism_properties => sub { !keys %$_ },
},
```

Which means that when you use the `MONGODB-X509` authentication scheme, you should not provide a password because if it is there the `sub { ! length }` will trigger and generate an error.

I guess the password is taken out of your URL, in the `host` parameter, so try instead with:

```
host => 'mongodb://username@ip_address1:port_number, ip_address2:port_number,ip_address3:port_number/myDB?ssl=true&replicaSet=mongo123'
```

(the username itself may be irrelevant in fact if you use a certificate)

The man page at https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::MongoClient#MONGODB-X509-(for-SSL-client-certificate) gives this example:

```
my $mc = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(
    host => "mongodb://sslmongo.example.com/",
    ssl => {
        SSL_ca_file   => "certs/ca.pem",
        SSL_cert_file => "certs/client.pem",
    },
    auth_mechanism => "MONGODB-X509",
    username       => "CN=XXXXXXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXXX,O=XXXXXXX,ST=XXXXXXXXXX,C=XX"
);
```

By the way and to be precise, it is not a TLS (better name than SSL) problem, it is a problem related to authentication with an X.509 certificate.

Comment: I'm getting the same error even after removing the password from the host URL.

Comment: @AbhijitRoy The password has to come from somewhere, the library sees it. Are you sure of your call to `MongoDB::MongoClient->new()`?

Comment: No I'm not sure of it.

Comment: I'm very new to this area. So, Could you please send me a complete demo for this? It would be very helpful for me if there is any way to execute the code without authentication.

Comment: @AbhijitRoy I have added the example from the manpage. Note that the URL is without any username or password. Try a simple case first, with only a name or an IP and then when it works make it more complex as needed. You have to many things going on the same time (not sure if your URL in `host` is valid, so start with a simple one)

Comment: Getting the folloing error if I pass only the IP address with port, MongoDB::SelectionError: No readable server available for matching read preference primary. MongoDB server status:
Topology type: Sharded; Member status:
  10.108.24.13:7018 (type: Unknown, error: MongoDB::HandshakeError: SSL connection failed for 10.108.24.13: Failed to load key from file (no PEM or DER) error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 or:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib error:0D0680A8:asn1

Comment: @AbhijitRoy "without authentication"? Surely not a good idea. But you control that in `/etc/mongod.conf`,  in `security`,  the key `authorization` could be set to `disabled` to remove any need to authenticate. This is however clearly not the road to follow to solve an authentication problem... See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security-options

Comment: @AbhijitRoy you may need `SSL_key_file` in the `ssl` block to point to the correct path

Comment: Thank you for sharing this valuable info and quick response as well.

Comment: Could you please share any demo for SSL_key_file?

Comment: @AbhijitRoy It is the path to the key file. At this point, it is no more a Perl issue, so we are getting offtopic here. I would recommend you start again from scratch, starting with simple things and build it up. Like, first without authentication, then simple authentication (username + password), then TLS connection, then X509 authentication. Otherwise you are following too many problems at the same time.

Comment: Still, I'm finding the solution, Even, ignoring the SSL certificate would also be fine. like: In Java, sslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true, same thing I need for Perl.